# React js Material-UI responsive table

Tags: reactjs, mobile, web-applications, responsive-design, material-ui

I am building a web application in react js and I'm using the material-ui components library. I'm using the table component and it looks good on desktop but I want it to adjust and look good also on mobile browser. Is material-ui supports such thing? How can I do it? Example of the current situation:
PC\Mobile:
[image: PC]

[image: Mobile]

Source code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'auto',
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 700,
  },
});

let id = 0;
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  id += 1;
  return { id, name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const data = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];

function SimpleTable(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Fat (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Carbs (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Protein (g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map(n => {
            return (
              <TableRow key={n.id}>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {n.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{n.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{n.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{n.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{n.protein}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}

SimpleTable.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleTable);
```

Answer (score 11):

For **Material-UI** tables `padding-right` and `padding-left` of every table cell should be changed,
you can have code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nwmkn9z9yj)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'hide',
  },
  table: {
    minWidth: 340,
  },
  tableCell: {
    paddingRight: 4,
    paddingLeft: 5
  }
});

let id = 0;
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  id += 1;
  return { id, name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const data = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];

function SimpleTable(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric className={classes.tableCell}>Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric className={classes.tableCell}>Fat (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric className={classes.tableCell}>Carbs (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric className={classes.tableCell}>Protein (g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.map(n => {
            return (
              <TableRow key={n.id}>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row" className={classes.TableCell}>
                  {n.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric className={classes.tableCell}>{n.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric className={classes.tableCell}>{n.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric className={classes.tableCell}>{n.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric className={classes.tableCell}>{n.protein}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}

SimpleTable.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleTable);
```

To make it **responsive** you need to use **[Grid system](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/)** in the first place, For example this is grid system for full-page:

```
 <Grid item xs={12}>
     <Table/>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! Attached my source code of the table component

Comment: answer added to my previous one

Comment: @El.Your code snipped runs into an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: It's not working with stack overflow snippet, use sandbox code snippets